# Execute batch file from Java code

Tags: java

I tried to run the batch file from java code, bat file is running but in bat file internally it is calling proxyServer.js file.This .js file is not running.
Below is the sample code.

```
try {
    String path="cmd /c start C:\\AxoneES_Viewers_Integration-2016Q3-SNAPSHOT_201609021003\\AxoneViewers.bat";

    Runtime rn=Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process pr=rn.exec(path);

} catch(IOException ex) {
         System.out.println("Exception Found");
}
```

As i mentioned internally it is calling .js file where they declared path of the .js file, below  is the code , which declared the path.
cd viewers\apps\maxq\
 node proxyServer.js

while running the bat file it is not able to find the path of .js file and it not running.

Can you help me is there any approach to execute the bat file from java.

Comment: Can you run your batch file without java?

Comment: So you want to use java, to call a bat script that runs a js file. Djeez.

Comment: I need to run the batch file using java only.While i am running batch file internally it will call .js file.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the batch file to use absolute file names instead of relative file names. You mentioned your batch file has the lines

```
cd viewers\apps\maxq\
node proxyServer.js
```

Change the first line to something like `C:\full\path\to\viewers\apps\maxq\`. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10288252/6451976) for the difference between absolute and relative file names.

Comment: I have changed the path in batch file and it is working,but there is condition that i should not change in the batch file.That where i am facing issue for running this batch file