# October cms attaching file with mail

Tags: php, email

This is the code i used:

```
Mail::send('acme.blog::mail.welcome', $data, function ($message) {
    //

    $message->attach($pathToFile);
});
```

Comment: attach method accepts the full path to the file as its first argument. What should be the full path to a file... This is fpr october cms

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question to include your comment.

Comment: By the way, both relative and absolute/Full path can be used as $pathToFile. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/a/10288252/2073920 to know the difference between relative and absolute path

Comment: Please add the value of `$pathToFile` and where you are setting the value

Comment: $pathToFile= "storage/app/uploads/public"; .. should i define the path like this? Abdul?